# JQUERY / JAVASCRIPT - Get multiple values out of .find command

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a JSP page with a form. When I submit the form, it build and gerenates a JSON string that I do an AJAX post with.

I have a problem though, I need to get multiple values out of the form,and I am using the following to do this:

```
 .find('input[name=item1])
 .not('input[type=hidden]')
```

How can I do this to get inputs with names item1, item2 and item3?

I tried this but it didn't work?

```
 .find('input[name=item1][name=item2][name=item3]')
```

Below is my code for this:

```
    // Create JSON based data object
    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });

        return o;
    };

    // Form Submission
    $('#form').submit( function() {

        // Create data array, used for building request message
        var data = {
            request: { 
                requestType: "request",
                fields: [ { 
                    itemX1 : '1',
                    itemX2 : '2',
                    itemX3 : '3'
                } ] 
            }
        };  

        // Create field array based variables for request message
        var fields = {
            fields: [ { 
                itemX1 : null,
                itemX2 : null,
                itemX3 : null
            } ] 
        };              

        // Get reqired data from the form submitted
        fields = $('#form')
        //.find('input')
        .find('input[name=lmBtId][name=my]')  
        .not('input[type=hidden]')    
        .serializeObject();

        // Set the field array variables with data
        fields.itemX1 = '1';
        fields.itemX2 = '2';
        fields.itemX3 = '3';

        // Update data array with newly updated field array
        data.request.fields = [fields];
        var finalData = JSON.stringify(data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page will provide information on selectors,

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Please try this

```
.find('input[name=item1],[name=item2],[name=item3]')
```

And do something for each of them add,

```
.each(function(){
//code here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
.find('input[name^=item]');
```

it will select all input which name are starting with item.

You can get a property value if containing any thing then you can use

```
.find('selector[propname*=containingvalue']);
```

if want to select which value ends with then

```
.find('selector[propname$=endwith']);
```

Comment: This was good, but I used the .each to do stuff with the values

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[name="test"], input[name="test2"]').each(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});​
```

Here's a [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hQq8B/)